# What is the correct way to retrieve all data and then filter into table view?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving Firebase data successfully and loading it into my tableview. On the initial load I'm querying the data based on dates so it only loads the data that have dates after the current date. I also have a "Past" button that queries data the same way but only showing data that have dates before the current date. It works, BUT I'm retrieving data on each button click and it seems to slow down performance and crashed at times. Is this the way to do this? Or in what way can I load ALL data and the query/filter with buttons?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//Retrieving data from Firebase
    refReleases = Database.database().reference().child("releases");
    _ = refReleases.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryStarting(atValue: currentDate).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.releasesData.removeAll()
          for releases in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let releaseObject = releases.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let releaseName = releaseObject?["releaseName"]
                let releaseType = releaseObject?["releaseType"]
                let releasePrice = releaseObject?["releasePrice"]
                let releaseDate = releaseObject?["releaseDate"]
                let releaseImage = releaseObject?["releaseImage"]
                let releasetag = releaseObject?["releasetag"]
                let releaseStyleCode = releaseObject?["releaseStyleCode"]
                let release = ReleaseModel(releasetype: releaseType as! String?, releasename: releaseName as! String?, releaseprice: releasePrice as! String?, releasedate: releaseDate as! String?, releaseimage: releaseImage as! String?, releasetag: releasetag as! String?, releasestylecode: releaseStyleCode as! String?) 
                self.releasesData.insert(release, at: 0)
            }
            self.releasesData.reverse()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    )}
}

//"Past" button
@IBAction func past(_ sender: UIButton) {
    refReleases = Database.database().reference().child("releases");
    _ = refReleases.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEnding(atValue: currentDate).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.releasesData.removeAll()
            for releases in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let releaseObject = releases.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let releaseName = releaseObject?["releaseName"]
                let releaseType = releaseObject?["releaseType"]
                let releasePrice = releaseObject?["releasePrice"]
                let releaseDate = releaseObject?["releaseDate"]
                let releaseImage = releaseObject?["releaseImage"]
                let releasetag = releaseObject?["releasetag"]
                let releaseStyleCode = releaseObject?["releaseStyleCode"]
                let release = ReleaseModel(releasetype: releaseType as! String?, releasename: releaseName as! String?, releaseprice: releasePrice as! String?, releasedate: releaseDate as! String?, releaseimage: releaseImage as! String?, releasetag: releasetag as! String?, releasestylecode: releaseStyleCode as! String?)
                self.releasesData.insert(release, at: 0)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    )}
```

Comment: Correct way is fetch data at once and filter locally.

Comment: @TheTiger how do I filter locally?

Comment: Could you share your crash message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically adding observers every time you click the "Past" button.
`observe` method will fire every time the value changes in the Database.
Also, remove the `handle` is `viewDidDisappear`.

If you want to manually read the data once, use `observeSingleEvent` method.
It will only fire once.

Also, take a look at this [firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html).
It shows where to put listeners.

```
var handle: DatabaseHandle!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //  Retrieving data from Firebase
    refReleases = Database.database().reference().child("releases")
}

override func viewWillApear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    handle = refReleases
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
        .queryStarting(atValue: currentDate)
        .observe(.value) { snapshot in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.releasesData.removeAll()

                for releases in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let releaseObject = releases.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let releaseName = releaseObject?["releaseName"]
                    let releaseType = releaseObject?["releaseType"]
                    let releasePrice = releaseObject?["releasePrice"]
                    let releaseDate = releaseObject?["releaseDate"]
                    let releaseImage = releaseObject?["releaseImage"]
                    let releasetag = releaseObject?["releasetag"]
                    let releaseStyleCode = releaseObject?["releaseStyleCode"]

                    let release = ReleaseModel(
                        releasetype: releaseType as! String?,
                        releasename: releaseName as! String?,
                        releaseprice: releasePrice as! String?,
                        releasedate: releaseDate as! String?,
                        releaseimage: releaseImage as! String?,
                        releasetag: releasetag as! String?,
                        releasestylecode: releaseStyleCode as! String?) 
                    self.releasesData.insert(release, at: 0)
                }
                self.releasesData.reverse()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let handle = handle {
        refReleases.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> BUT I'm retrieving data on each button click and it seems to slow down
>   performance and crashed at times

because you are blocking main thread, you can do that in `Dispatch.main.async {}`

Comment: @CARGI I do what in `Dispatch.main.async {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Jay Lee is right. You should not add observer every click. You can do that in your past button click check your query. If it is exist, remove it.

```
        private var queryPast: Query?; // be sure firebase query. I do not remember. 
         override func viewDidLoad() 
        {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            //Retrieving data from Firebase
                refReleases = Database.database().reference().child("releases");
                _= refReleases.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryStarting(atValue: currentDate).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                        self.releasesData.removeAll()
                      for releases in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                            let releaseObject = releases.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            let releaseName = releaseObject?["releaseName"]
                            let releaseType = releaseObject?["releaseType"]
                            let releasePrice = releaseObject?["releasePrice"]
                            let releaseDate = releaseObject?["releaseDate"]
                            let releaseImage = releaseObject?["releaseImage"]
                            let releasetag = releaseObject?["releasetag"]
                            let releaseStyleCode = releaseObject?["releaseStyleCode"]
                            let release = ReleaseModel(releasetype: releaseType as! String?, releasename: releaseName as! String?, releaseprice: releasePrice as! String?, releasedate: releaseDate as! String?, releaseimage: releaseImage as! String?, releasetag: releasetag as! String?, releasestylecode: releaseStyleCode as! String?) 
                            self.releasesData.insert(release, at: 0)
                        }
                        self.releasesData.reverse()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
                )}
            }

            //"Past" button
            @IBAction func past(_ sender: UIButton) {
          if (self.queryPast != nil)
          {
             self.queryPast.removeObserver();
              // I DO NOT REMEMBER currently syntax. but you have  do something 
  like that.
          }
                refReleases = Database.database().reference().child("releases");
                self.queryPast = refReleases.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEnding(atValue: currentDate);
       self.queryPast.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                        self.releasesData.removeAll()
                        for releases in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                            let releaseObject = releases.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            let releaseName = releaseObject?["releaseName"]
                            let releaseType = releaseObject?["releaseType"]
                            let releasePrice = releaseObject?["releasePrice"]
                            let releaseDate = releaseObject?["releaseDate"]
                            let releaseImage = releaseObject?["releaseImage"]
                            let releasetag = releaseObject?["releasetag"]
                            let releaseStyleCode = releaseObject?["releaseStyleCode"]
                            let release = ReleaseModel(releasetype: releaseType as! String?, releasename: releaseName as! String?, releaseprice: releasePrice as! String?, releasedate: releaseDate as! String?, releaseimage: releaseImage as! String?, releasetag: releasetag as! String?, releasestylecode: releaseStyleCode as! String?)
                            self.releasesData.insert(release, at: 0)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
                )}
```